# Android photo viewer that doesn't blank screen

Tags: screen, photos

I have many photos of my family on my phone. I like to draw with my daughters and I invariably end up drawing family members. It would be really nice to have an android phone app that displays a photo and simply leaves it there without allowing the screen to dim or to lock the phone. Certainly such permissions are commonly used by video player apps, but photo viewer apps seem to always allow screen dimming and phone locking.

Is there such a photo viewer app? I would expect a handful, but haven't been able to find one.

(Yes, I know display costs battery, and that if I don't close it my battery will be drained.)

Comment: You could just turn the screen timeout off in Settins > Display while you use it, it's not elegant but might just be easier. Alternatively there are play store apps for this, but they basically just do that. Alternatively there is a Keep screen on while charging option you could use if it is convenient to leve it plugged in while you draw together.

Answer (score 1):

I have looked for that kind of app in all my installed apps but no photo viewer requests such permission. I really doubt there is a photo viewer that keeps your screen awake, because of battery drain (which is not exactly what an average user would be looking for)

Maybe what you should do instead is to search in Google Play for an app made specifically for keeping your screen awake, and use it with your favorite photo viewer. There are lots of them, and many are free, like this one ([Keep Screen On](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nbondarchuk.android.keepscn))